# Resize Height of elements when Resize window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery. Can't figure out how to do this.
I have multiple sections width different heights:

```
<section id="1" class="something" style="height:111px; background:red;">1</section>
<section id="2" class="something" style="height:222px; background:blue;">2</section>
<section id="3" class="something" style="height:333px; background:green;">3</section>
```

My jQuery scales the height of each section when the window is smaller than 500px:

```
var org_height = $('.something').height();

$(window).resize(function() {

    $(".something").each(function() {

        var win = $(window).width();
        var height = $('.something').height();

        if(win < 500) {
            y = 500 - win;
            $('.something').css("height",org_height-y/3+"px");
        }
        else {
            $('.something').css("height",org_height+"px");
        }
    });   

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/owtz31jj/

How can I store the original height of each section and scale them depending on each height and back to the original height again. I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.fn.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
// Store original height for each .something
$(".something").each(function() {
    $(this).data('org_height', $(this).height());
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var win = $(window).width();
    $(".something").each(function() {
        // Get the value storred in org_height using jQuery.fn.data
        var org_height = $(this).data('org_height'); 
        if(win < 500) {
            var y = 500 - win;
            $(this).css("height", org_height - y/3);
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("height", org_height);
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: That was quick. Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

Comment: No problem. You see how you can use `$(this)` inside the each function? That will make sure that you get the org_height from the corresponding element.

Comment: Yep, i like jQuery more and more ;)

Comment: @user5379464 Yes jQuery is really good at manipulation the DOM, and have a really good API: https://api.jquery.com/ Btw: Remember to accept the answer if it answered your question :-)